# List Comprehension Help: Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I need help with finding the outcome for the given definitions using python and list comprehension.

```
firstSentence = ["Help", "me", "stack", "overflow", "you're", "my", "only", "hope"]
secondSentence = ["I", "hope", "you're", "enjoying", "the", "riddles", "I've", "created"]
```

What's supposed to printed : `['HelpI', 'Helpthe', 'meI', 'stackI', 'stackhope', 'stackthe', "stackI've", 'overflowI', 'overflowhope', "overflowyou're", 'overflowthe', 'overflowriddles', "overflowI've", 'overflowcreated', "you'reI", "you'rehope", "you'rethe", "you'reI've", 'myI', 'onlyI', 'onlythe', 'hopeI', 'hopethe']`

I know this one has to do with combinations that has to be less than the secondsentence, but I'm not sure of how to execute that.

Using list comprehension: how do I combine first and second sentence given that the length cannot be more than secondsentence.

Comment: Can you explain *why* the output is supposed to be what it is and what you've tried?

Comment: `[s + t for s in firstSentence for t in secondSentence if len(s) > len(t)]` gives what your're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

To get clear grab of list comprehension first let's try to get desired output using nested loop:

```
firstSentence = ["Help", "me", "stack", "overflow", "you're", "my", "only", "hope"]
secondSentence = ["I", "hope", "you're", "enjoying", "the", "riddles", "I've", "created"]

result = []
for firstWord in firstSentence:
    for secondWord in secondSentence:
        if len(secondWord) < len(firstWord):
            result.append(firstWord+secondWord)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['HelpI', 'Helpthe', 'meI', 'stackI', 'stackhope', 'stackthe', "stackI've", 'overflowI', 'overflowhope', "overflowyou're", 'overflowthe', 'overflowriddles', "overflowI've", 'overflowcreated', "you'reI", "you'rehope", "you'rethe", "you'reI've", 'myI', 'onlyI', 'onlythe', 'hopeI', 'hopethe']
```

Now let's convert this nested loop with list comprehension:

```
result = [firstWord+secondWord for firstWord in firstSentence for secondWord in secondSentence if len(secondWord) < len(firstWord)]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['HelpI', 'Helpthe', 'meI', 'stackI', 'stackhope', 'stackthe', "stackI've", 'overflowI', 'overflowhope', "overflowyou're", 'overflowthe', 'overflowriddles', "overflowI've", 'overflowcreated', "you'reI", "you'rehope", "you'rethe", "you'reI've", 'myI', 'onlyI', 'onlythe', 'hopeI', 'hopethe']
```

N.B.: Variables are not declared or being used as `camelCase` in Python. It prefers lowercase variable names where words separated by underscore (`_`).

From Python PEP-8 guideline:

> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by
>   underscores as necessary to improve readability. Variable names follow the same convention as function names.

### Reference:

- [PEP 8 Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names)

Comment: Thank you so much @arsho this helped a lot!! one quick question. What if I wanted to get the first characters of each word to be combined with each other? like this for an example: [('H', 'I'), ('H', 'h'), ('H', 'y'), ('H', 'e'), ('H', 't'), ('H', 'r'), ('H', 'I'), ('H', 'c'), ('m', 'I'), ('m', 'h'), ('m', 'y'), ('m', 'e'), ('m', 't'), ('m', 'r'), ('m', 'I') ..

Comment: @David,
Use first index of each word rather that the whole word. For example, `firstWord[0]` will print the first character of the `firstWord` variable. I'm glad that the answer helped you. You may accept if it really helps. Cheers!

Comment: figured it out! thank you so much, I appreciate your help greatly!!